# Knockout.js - Stop rerendering of elements in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

On my viewModel I have an observable array called 'bays', which contains one or more 'bay' objects. Each 'bay' object then contains an observable array called 'products', which can contain 'product' objects.
With my markup looking like:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: bays">
    <div class="bay" data-bind="foreach: products">
        <div class="product">
        <!-- Product innards -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the product object is moved from one bay to another then the product element, and everything inside it, seems to be destroyed and then re-created, as can be seen in this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mXyzs/20/

As my application can move hundreds of products between bays at once and is having to re-create them all it is causing a performance issue. Is there any way that knockout can re-use the existing product html, seeing as the object backing them isn't changing, rather than destroying the product elements and re-creating them all?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mXyzs/16/ I added an annoying alert, but you should see that the object is only created once.

Comment: one simple way to check if they are recreated. Use `data-bind="text: new Date()"`. This will show you the time when the element is created. Instead of using an annoying alert.

Comment: @Joe I've edited my question and my jfiddle as I realise I was being a bit unclear. I am referring to the product elements on the page being destroyed and then knockout creating them again in the new bay, despite the product object that is backing the bindings not changing.

Comment: @Loïc Thanks for that suggestion, I've updated my jfiddle and it makes it a lot clearer that the product element is being re-created

Comment: Not exactly an answer but it my be a good idea to checkout this out: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/10/29/knockout-2-2-0-released/ There is something about moved node handled as delete/add now just a move.

Comment: Move detection only works when an item is moved within a single array and not between arrays as he is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Knockout version 2.2.0, the `foreach` binding will detect moved items and not re-render the UI for those items. But in your case, you're moving items from one array to another so this optimization doesn't apply (since it's only for a single `foreach` binding).

To take advantage of `foreach`'s ability, we can flatten the structure into a single array.

```
var result = [];
ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.bays(), function(bay) {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(bay.products(), function(product) {
        product.bay(bay);
        result.push(product);
    });
});
```

If we use a `computed` for the flattened list, we can reference that in a single `foreach` binding.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: flattenedProducts">
    <div class="product">
    <!-- Product innards -->
    </div>
</div>
```

With this method, although the products will be sorted by bay, all the product `div`s will be siblings. So you won't be able to have a `div` per bay.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/3ZUxZ/

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, the product element is NOT being recreated. I added a created property to your product object

```
var product = function (data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);  
    this.created = new Date();
};
```

When clicking the Move to bay button, the created date does not seem to change. It is merely being added to another observable array and that element gets painted.

One thing I will not through. If you are doing this push to an abservable array or pop from an observable array in a loop or something, it is costly and you will see a performance issue.

Ryan Neimeyer talks about this here http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Hope that helps!
Cheers!
Suj